# New flag suggestion

Tags: feature-request

More often than not the correct answer here is "Have you considered learning philosophy or art instead?"

Now this is kind of blunt but i stress that it correct answer most of the time.

Comment: this version of the question makes no sense... what is the question exactly?

Comment: I've removed an impolite comment. Please assume that everyone is communicating in good faith and maintain a welcoming atmosphere.

Comment: This edit seems to completely remove the original question and makes the two current answers hard to follow.

Comment: The original question has been restored.

Answer (score 3):

Note: this answer responds to language in a previous version ([v1](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/12572/1)) of the question.

Flags are for communicating with reviewers and moderators.  If an existing flag doesn't describe your concern about a post, you can enter custom text instead, which will be visible only to the diamond moderators and the Stack Exchange staff. Please do not respond to low-quality questions by suggesting that the diamond moderators should study philosophy or art. We're fortunate to have a diamond mod team of very well-rounded people.

A comment under a question suggesting that the asker should study art instead of asking about physics would probably be flagged as impolite and removed.

The flag you are looking for is "should be closed," which puts the question into a review queue.  There's lots of detail about this in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise for this seems very flawed to me.

If you believe the correct answer to any question here is:

> "Have you considered learning philosophy or art instead?"

I think you will want to rethink how you approach answers.  Asking the user another question is *rarely* an answer; and is never a good answer on it's own.

This specific question is not helpful for a vast majority of the questions here.  Even if asking rhetorical questions were an appropriate close flag, this one would not have any practical use here when we already have off topic flags.

Comment: What does off topic even mean? I really don't understand.. There is "correctness" and there is too much "correctness" where the original message you hoped to convey is just not there world wide speaking.

Comment: Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic regarding what is on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: @user192234 The above comment is for you, not JMac.